# Behaviour of arr[i] = i++ and i = i + 1 statements in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, c++14, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

In the C and C++ languages, the `arr[i] = i++;` statement invokes undefined behavior. Why does the statement `i = i + 1;` not invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: When asking questions like this, you need to focus on a *single language*, not "C and C++" any more than you'd ask about "C# and Java".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**<sup>*Since this was originally tagged with [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and not any specific version(s), the below answer is a generic answer to the problem. However, please note for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), `C++17` onwards, the behaviour has changed. Please see this [answer by Barry to know more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348568/2173917)*</sup>**

---

For the statement

```
arr[i] = i++;
```

the value of `i` is *used* in both the operands, RHS(right-hand-side) and LHS(left-hand-side), and in one of the cases, the value is being modified (as a side effect of post `++`) where there's no [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/2173917) in between to determine which value of `i` should be considered. You can also check [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/2173917) for more on this.

On the other hand, for `i = i + 1`, the value of `i` is *used* only in RHS, the computed result is stored in LHS, in other words, there's no ambiguity. We can write the same statement as `i++`, which

- reads the value of `i`
- Increments it by `1`
- stores it back to `i`

in a well-defined sequence. Hence, no issues.

Comment: Nice answer to a non-duplicate variant of this corner of the language.

Comment: It's been a few years C++ abandoned "sequenced points" in favor of a more convoluted description based on "sequenced after" that made for example `i=++i;` legal code.

Comment: `i = i + 1` is not equivalent to `i++`.   It is equivalent in effect to `++i`.     Compare the effect of `j = i = i+1` with `j = ++i` and `j = i++` to see the distinction (remembering that assignment operators are right to left associative, so `j = i = i+1` is equivalent to `j = (i = i+1)`).

Comment: @Peter well, you may be right, but my answer was pointed to the exact statement mentioned, so I guess in that, it does not make any difference, does it?

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you sir for the kind words. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - my problem is that you wrote your second para in a way that suggests `i = i+1` and `i++` are equivalent, when they are not.  Making that suggestion is unnecessary to answering the question, and is also misleading.

Comment: Note that this changes in C++17, where `arr[i] = i++` is [actually well-defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (it gets the current value of `i`, increments `i`, and then sets `arr[i]` to the old value of `i`. Thus, it is equivalent to `{auto tmp = i; i++; arr[i] = tmp;}`).

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for the reminder.. I guess the C++17 was not explicitly mentioned and I am no expert in C++ either, so from that point, my answer was incomplete. Now there's an answer from Barry which complements mine, and I'm just now adding a link of that to mine. Hope that will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 13):

Note that this *will change* in C++17. In C++17, `arr[i] = i++` does not invoke undefined behavior. This is due to the following change in [[expr.ass]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1):

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.**

That is, we do `i++` *then* we do `arr[i]` *then* we perform the assignment. The now well-defined ordering is:

```
auto src = i++;
auto& dst = arr[i];
dst = src;
```

Comment: Even though this now works, it is still a horrendously brittle expression. Fortunately, if you are using GCC, you can keep this garbage expression undefined by using `-fno-strong-eval-order`.

Comment: @KevinZ why fortunately? What's the benefit of having extra undefined behavior in this case?

Comment: Yeah, it's bad to write such an expression, purely on account of how obfuscated and faux-clever it looks - but it is worse to leave a timebomb in the code and force your compiler to avoid complying with the new Standard. Writing good code should be encouraged by reasoning, not discouraged by UB... _you hope, if the UB ever detectably manifests before it's too late_. In fact, frankly, advising people to rely on something being UB, and observably so, is incredibly stupid. People who would write this code need to be explained out of it; they're highly unlikely to be running with UBsan or whatever

Comment: @Ruslan So that GCC will not unnecessarily pessimize on ilp on my perfectly sane code. More fundamentally, the act of storing to a memory location twice is a stupid idea in it very essence. By defining its semantics, C++17 has essentially encouraged it. It's much easier to deduce that double store is stupid and illegal than to remember any sequence of broken broken semantics regarding it misuse.

Comment: @KevinZ How is `arr[i] = i++` a double store, unless there are additionally aliasing issues which haven’t been mentioned?

Comment: @barry sir, instead of copying the content, I've just mentioned a link to your answer with due credits (_I believe, please let me know if any modification needed_) in mine, hope that's okay with you. Cheers!!

Comment: @DanielH You are right; it's meant store+read that does not emit a clear ordering.

Answer (score 9):

For C99, we have:

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> 2. Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>    modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
>    shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

In `arr[i] = i++`, the value of `i` is only modified once. But `arr[i]` also reads from `i`, and this value is not used to determine the new value of `i`. That's why it has undefined behavior.

On the other hand, in `i = i + 1` we read `i` in order to compute `i + 1`, which is used as the new value of `i`. Therefore this expression is fine.

Answer (score 8):

```
arr[i] = i++;
```

implies that

- right hand expression is evaluated before assignment
- subscript operator is evaluated before assignment

but contains ambiguity regarding the order of right hand expression evaluation and subscript operator evaluation, compiler is free to treat it as

```
auto & val{arr[i]};
i++;
auto const rval{i};
val = rval;
```

or as

```
i++;
auto & val{arr[i]};
auto const rval{i};
val = rval;
```

or as (same result as above)

```
i++;
auto const rval{i};
auto & val{arr[i]};
val = rval;
```

Which may produce unpredictable result, while

```
i = i + 1;
```

dos not have any ambiguity, right hand expression is evaluated before assignment:

```
auto const rval{i + 1};
auto & val{i};
val = rval;
```

or (same result as above)

```
auto & val{i};
auto const rval{i + 1};
val = rval;
```

Comment: Or as: `undefined();`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example a [i] = i++, if i = 3 for example, do you think a [i] is evaluated first, or i++? In one case, the value 3 would be stored in a [3], in the other case, it would be stored in a [4]. It's obvious that **we have a problem** here. No sane person would dare writing that code unless they found a guarantee what exactly will happen here. (Java gives that guarantee).

What would you think could be a problem with i = i + 1? The language must read i first to calculate i+1, then store that result. There is nothing here that could be wrong. Same with a [i] = i+1. Evaluating i+1, unlike i++, doesn't change i. So if i = 3, the number 4 must be stored in a [3].

Various languages have various rules to fix the problem with a [i] = i++. Java *defines* what happens: Expressions are evaluated left to right including their side effects. C defines it as undefined behaviour. C++ doesn't make it *undefined* behaviour but just unspecified. It says that either a[i] or i++ is evaluated first, and the other one next, but it doesn't say which one. So unlike C where *anything* can happen, C++ defines that only one of two things can happen. Obviously that's one thing too many to be acceptable in your code.