# Maximize the sum of arr[i]*i

Tags: greedy

I have been given been an array `arr` and the need is to maximize `arr[i]*i`.
A simple solution given at [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximize-sum-arrii](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximize-sum-arrii/) is to sort the array and then find the sum. But, how shall I confirm the fact that the resultant sum will be maximum over all the possible answers.

Comment: This question seems like it's more about a mathematical proof than about programming.

Comment: I want the reason for its greediness.

Comment: Because `arr[i]*i + arr[i+1]*(i+1) >= arr[i]*(i+1) + arr[i+1]*i` when `arr[i] >= arr[i-1]`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341215/behaviour-of-arri-i-and-i-i-1-statements-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question is way too old but as a mathematical proof for why the resultant sum will be maximum is guaranteed by **Rearrangement Inequality**. Here's a link to its statement and proof [here in brilliant page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/), and now to apply it in this case we know that
n - 1 > n - 2 > n -3 > ... > 0 and after sorting array **in ascending order** we know that
arr[n - 1] ≥ arr[n - 2] ≥ arr[n - 3] ≥ ... ≥ arr[0] and now apply the inequality and voilà you get the maximum of Σi * arr[i]

**PS**: in the link of inequality, what π(x) means in simpler terms is all possible arrangements or **permutations in a mathy way** of array which exactly are
**n factorial or n!**. To understand more about this you can check [this link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations/)